# Facebook PHP SDK - The correct approach when posting updates

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

What is the best approach to posting updates on  users timelines/walls from the PHP SDK? At the minute I capture the FB id via connect and then store in the database, we also store the user access token. My question is how do I go about posting to a users wall, I know I use the api within the app but I don't know if I simply loop through the user ids and post for each individual.

Does anyone know id Facebook incorporates a rate limit when making posts to Facebook.

Any advice would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) suggests the following thresholds :-

> (>5M MAU) or (>100M API calls per day) or (>50M impressions per day).

So it would be safe to assume that the impressions limit might be the post limit on the app, so I think you should keep your posts <= 50M per day, if you think you might exceed it then use the [contact form](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=206103619499608) at Facebook's platform policy.

Answer (score 0):

there is no limit, its all about your posts complaint amount. when your complaint glare to facebook admins, they perceive your application as a spam then remove